# What cause extreme heat when electricity connect to it?

Tags: electric-machine

I want to know is there a item/chemical etc, that cause extreme heat if it comes into contact with even a small bit of electric currents?

I ask cause I am doing a school project and I need something to generation heat using electricity as it would be very covenant. Thanks

Update: Sorry this question was unclear. I have done a bit of research since posting and hopeful I can make this more clear. I am trying to find away to amplify heat created by joules. ohmic heating is kind of what I'm talking about. How can I make a large volume of heat using that law? Do I need a large amount of electricity flowing or could I use a small bit of electricity and some how amplify it.

Comment: The question is unclear. I think you need to make some more research. 
But i guess combustion engine and a spark plug is an example. Keep in mind that there is no such thing as energy being produced, it is conserved inside each finite system.

Comment: Flammable materials?

Comment: I update my question

Comment: Yes, ohmic heating turns all your electrical energy into heat. If you want more heat you need more electricity. Conservation of energy means that 1 joule of non-heat is never going to give you more than one joule of heat. Unless you steal it from somewhere else with a heat pump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want more heat energy out than electrical energy you put in.  Conservation of energy means that this therefore requires some other form of energy to be put in, which is then controlled electrically.

The question then comes down to what other form should this energy take.  This depends on your application.  One obvious way to get a lot of heat is via chemical reaction.  It's easy enough to initiate a exothermic chemical reaction with electricity, but controlling it roughly proportional to some electric signal is more difficult.  One possibility may be electrically controlling a valve that lets more or less fuel into a combustion chamber.  It gets more tricky when the total output needs to be able to go to 0, since then you need a way to start up the chemical reaction, which can be quite different from sustaining it.  Traditional solutions include pilot lights or spark ignitors.  Or, you can chose chemicals that react exothermically on contact.  These will be harder to procure and may attract unwanted attention from the authorities.

If you put enough uranium or plutonium close enough with some carbon rods separating things, you can have the electric signal control how much the carbon rods inserted into the pile or not.  This controls the magnitude of the chain reaction.  The advantage is that this method can produce large amounts of heat for small amounts of material, but getting the material will be difficult.  The system can also go into exponential runaway if carbon rods are removed too far.  This will have bad consequences, so overall I don't recommend this method.

Answer (score 2):

The overarching principle is that conservation of energy applies in a closed system. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy

A very common example of this the combustion of fuel in a spark-ignition engine. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spark-ignition_engine, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_cycle

An extreme example would be triggering a nuclear explosive.

In these these examples the potential (stored) energy in the device is liberated as heat, mechanical action, etc; after the reaction has been initiated by a bit of heat provided by electrical system.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can 'amplify' the amount of heat you getc i.e. output more energy as heat then the amount of electrical energy you put in is if you consume some sort of fuel e.g. use electricity to spark a fire. Energy, including heat must come from somewhere, if it's not from the electricity it has to be from something else like the fuel.